# SQL query to union several tables with different number of columns

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, union

I have several tables with the first three rows identical and the rest different (in numbers as well). I want to union all tables into one, with first three columns as they are and the rest concatenated together into a single column named as "description". Now, I was able to do this manually but i have lots of tables. can a while loop be used, with variables? or is it doable?

Comment: Why is this tagged both MySQL and SQL Server?  Which database are you really using?

Comment: I suspect that it's not doable.

Comment: Show some example data and expected result.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to join the tables together.  In MySQL, this would look like:

```
select t1.col1, t1.col2, t1.col3,
       concat(t1.col4, t2.col4, t3.col4) as description
from t1 left outer join
     t2
     on t1.col1 = t2.col1 and t1.col2 = t2.col2 and t1.col3 = t2.col3 left outer join
     t3
     on t1.col1 = t3.col1 and t1.col2 = t3.col2 and t1.col3 = t3.col3
```